# use array element as var UILabel name in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to build a key/values pair, for referencing later.
The array will hold a index reference, and it's values inside. One of the values is a video matching the index, and the other value is the corresponding label name (so I can change the color when video is played).

Here is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var videos = [5: ["urltovideo1", "locationOne"], 7: ["urltovideo2", "locationTwo"]]
    var bg: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var locationOne: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        bg = videos[5]![1]
        bg.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    }
}
```

I get an error "Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type 'UILabel!'" 
I tried  "bg = UILabel(videos[5]![1])" and get an error ""Argument labels '(_:)' do not match any available overloads""

Any ideas on how to fix it or better way to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution for you:

```
@objc var locationOne: UILabel!
@objc var locationTwo: UILabel!
var videos = [5: ["urltovideo1", "locationOne"], 7: ["urltovideo2", "locationTwo"]]
var bg: UILabel! = UILabel()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let bg = self.value(forKey: videos[5]![1]) as? UILabel {
        bg.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    }
}
```

@objc is required to make `self.value(forKey:)` working properly - you have to add it for every property you want to access via this method.

Comment: it's there, above viewDidLoad @IBOutlet weak var locationOne: UILabel!

Comment: OK then you need to add this code and add a better explanation on what you want to achieve.

Comment: THANK YOU very much! it worked perfectly! I'm sorry if I missed details, I'm new to this whole programming thing..